In my angular the checkboxes are behaving weirdly
I just started learning angular and started with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWhRMyyF7nc (I'm at the end section 2_. I tried to follow everything from and change it angular 17. But I encountered a bug. Basically I have my first project that is sort of wishlist to which you add wishes that are displayed as checkboxes and you check to mark them as fulfilled. And you can select if you want to display only fulfilled, unfulfilled or all wishes. Everything consists of single component. Here's html of it:
<div class = "containter">

  <form class = "form">
    <div>  
      <label class="infoText">Add your wish! </label>
      <input type="text" class="wishInput" [(ngModel)] = "wishToBeAdded" name ="wishAdder">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="submitButton" (click) = "$event.preventDefault(); addWish()">Submit</button>
  </form>


  <div class="selector">
    <select class = "wishSelector" [(ngModel)] = "filterOption">
      <option value = "0">All</option>
      <option value = "1">Fulfilled</option>
      <option value = "2">Unfulfilled</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <ul class ="wishList">
    <label style="font-weight: 800; font-size: large;">Wishlist:</label>
    <li>
      @for (item of visibleItems; track $index) {
        <label>
          {{$index + 1}}. {{item.wishName}} {{visibleItems[$index].isComplete}}
          <input type="checkbox" class = "checkbox" [checked] = "item.isComplete" (click) = "checkboxToggle(item, $event)">
        </label>
        <div>&NewLine;</div>
      } @empty {
        <label> There are no wishes in wishlist </label>
      }
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>


Here's typescript code:
import { Component, viewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { WishItem } from '../shared/modules/wishItem';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, FormsModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: WishItem[] = [];
  title = 'My FirstProject';
  wishToBeAdded : string = '';
  filterOption : string = '0'
  
  get visibleItems() : WishItem[] {
    switch(this.filterOption) {
      case "0":
        return this.items;
      case "1":
        return this.items.filter(value => value.isComplete);
      case "2":
        return this.items.filter(value => !value.isComplete);
    }
    return []
  }

  checkboxToggle(item: WishItem, element: any)
  {
    item.isComplete = !item.isComplete;
    this.items.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element.isComplete)
    });
    console.log(this.visibleItems);
  }

  addWish()
  {
    if(this.wishToBeAdded.length>0)
      this.items.push(new WishItem(this.wishToBeAdded));
    this.wishToBeAdded = '';
  }

}

However there is weird situation when the list is selected to display only fulfilled or unfulfilled elements and someone checks or unchecks one of elements. The element stops being displayed because its isComplete is changed but the next element in the list right after it is checked. The value of isComplete attribute of corresponding wishItem is still correct cause I started to print it to see if that's a problem but it's not. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or is it something about angular 17 because the tutorial is about some earlier version, or I don't understand something html.
(https://i.sstatic.net/A2sfSsb8.png)
Here's list of items after I checked test2 element.
After element is checked or unchecked from the list when it's being filtered there shouldn't be any change to other elements.

Should provide a stackblitz link of the code if you can so we can see it in action.


visibleItems() returns a shallow copy of your array (when a filter is applied) - see Array.prototype.filter()
checkboxToggle is passed a reference to the shallow copied array item and mutates it

Fundamentally the problem is that there is no "master" list of items to reference. When you perform a mutation on a shallow copied array item, you are doing just that - your change won't be reflected in items.
You could address the issue by tweaking your checkboxToggle() function:
// Item doesn't need to be passed in here, could benefit from just passing the index and avoiding the need to use .findIndex()
checkboxToggle(item: WishItem, element: any) {
  // Find the master copy of the item
  const itemIndex = items.findIndex(i => /* some predicate to identify the item */);
  if (itemIndex === -1) return;
  // Mutate the master copy of item
  this.items[itemIndex] = {
    ...this.items[itemIndex],
    isComplete: /* isComplete logic here */
  };
}


Your visibleItems() function should then reflect the change because it's executing on every re-render.

I don't think that's true because my function already changes the objects in master list cause as I understand the objects are passed as references. The problem is what I described in photos. Let's say I have 3 unfulfilled elements and and I'm filtering to display only unfulfilled elements. After I toggle checkbox of second element it dissapears (as it should and will be visible when  i change filter) but the problem is that the object after it (in this case third) will have toggled checkbox despite element having isComplete attribute as false because I also print it,
